# Estimating proportion of region cropped by proportions in random samples

Tags: confidence-interval, ecology, zero-inflation

I have a series of quadrats placed randomly across aerial photography of a region. In each quadrat I have estimated the proportion of the quadrat under cropping and my goal is to estimate the proportion of the region cropped with a 95% confidence interval around that estimate.

The data are provided below, but include 1s and 0s, and the vast bulk of values is 0. My question is : Is my best option to estimate the mean to use the standard approach (i.e., mean  = sum(x)/n; 95% CI = mean ± z(α/2) * σ(mean))
or is there are better approach / model for this sort of data.

[image]?

Comment: (+1) If you still have access to the photography, consider implementing an adaptive cluster sampling technique. This consists of analyzing the neighborhoods of the quadrats with positive cropping proportions *in a controlled way.* It is possible, with relatively little additional effort, to obtain unbiased estimates and accurate CIs that are much better than what you get with this simple random sample.  It is well explained in [Steven Thompson's book](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470402318.html).

Comment: Thanks Gung. I've looked into adaptive cluster sampling but it would seem to work on defining some level of crop cover as a threshold for presence / absence, then estimating proportion of occupied quadrats based on that threshold. So I am confused at what it actually estimates - if I set that threshold at 0% (ie >0% crop cover means the cell is occupied while 0% means unoccupied), does that mean I wind up estimating the proportion of the region that has >0% crop cover, and if so is that the same as the proportion of the region under crop cover?

Comment: You can use adaptive sampling techniques to estimate the *mean* value, not just the proportion of cells that have some property.